How I add first and last child in tailwind
Ex: [&>*:nth-child(even)]. This is even child's of pseudo class.
first:mt-20, it working
last:mt-20, it not working
I want the solution of above what I write for even child's.
 *:nth-child(even)]:mt-20">
//Enter your code here


Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must
include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to
reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful
to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.
